# Meaning of "$C^0$-small?"

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics

What are some small examples of what it means to be $C^0$-small?

The context I'm working in has this example:
Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to X$ be a smooth curve where $X$ is a smooth manifold. Then given the tangent bundle $TX\to X$, we have the pullback bundle $u^{*}TX \to \mathbb{R}$.
Now consider the space of sections $\Gamma(\mathbb{R}, u^{*}TX)$ and take $\psi: \mathbb{R}\to u^{*}TX$ to be one of these sections. They call $\psi$ "$C^{0}$-small"—what does that mean? If I'm not mistaken, $\psi$ should be viewed as a flowline... at least the exponential map of $\psi$ can perturb a flowline.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you defining the word "they"?

Comment: It's hard to know without some more context, but typically saying that a function $f$ is $C^0$-small usually means that, for whatever sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$, $\|f\|_{C^0} < \epsilon$, where $\|f\|_{C^0} = \sup_{x}|f(x)|$.

Comment: Here is the exact reference I'm using: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/gerig/files/note.pdf. The mention of $C^0$-small is half way down page 3.